# How do I align text with headings on the left margin?

Tags: alignment

Apologies for a grumpy newbie question - I'm feeling lost in Mathematica after the relatively simple world of, say, Jupyter.

My question is how can I modify the default notebook to align Section and Text cells on the left margin (with the Title cell).  I like to start out with a nice, straight left margin.  (I realize that evaluated mathematical input will be different - just talking about text here.)

I'm using 13.0.  I've looked at the object inspector but it's not clear to me which settings apply to positioning the cell at or relative to the left margin of the notebook.

Thanks, TB

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The default notebook contains a built-in style that you cannot change.  There is a possibility to make a custom `StyleSheet` of you liking and use it, if you believe that it pays off.  Try to search "How to change a StyleSheet" on this site.  First, however, I would recommend checking all the other StyleSheets. There are plenty of. Maybe, you will find something you like.

Comment: What you want to set are the `CellMargins`, and as Alexei said, it's best to do that through a stylesheet.  To start learning, look up "stylesheet" in the menu Help > Wolfram Documentation. Or dive right in with the second group of the Format menu.  And if "object inspector" was not a typo, then you're going to want to use the "Option Inspector."

Comment: Thanks all.  I've been exploring the other available stylesheets and will start with CellMargins" when I'm up to creating a new one.  Appreciate the responses.